# How the C++ avoid interleaved characters for cout

Tags: c++

As the C++ standard mentioned:

> Concurrent access to a synchronized (29.5.3.5) standard iostream
> object’s formatted and unformatted input (29.7.4.2) and output
> (29.7.5.2) functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads does
> not result in a data race (6.9.2).
>
> [Note 1 : Unsynchronized concurrent
> use of these objects and streams by multiple threads can result in
> interleaved characters. — end note]

So if I understand correctly, the Note 1 means that if I concurrent access to a synchronized standard iostream object (with `sync_with_stdio(true)`), there will be no interleaved characters. For example, I have 2 threads, one of them use cout to output `123`, the other one use cout to output `456`, then I can get `123456` or `456123` but not `142536`.

Is my understand correct? If it is correct, then can you point out how C++ implements that? Take gcc as an example, I checked the gcc code, and cout is just an instance of ostream, and ostream::sentry does not contain a lock to protect the output, and cout's stream buffer just put characters to the underlying standard output file one by one. Then how the system make sure that the characters are not interleaved?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's not what it means. It means that concurrent access will not create a data race. The second paragraph clarifies that interleaved output is a legal implementation.

Comment: @RaymondChen: then why the Note1 mentioned "Unsynchronized"? If I understand correctly, synchronized means sync_with_stdio(true) and  therefore unsynchronized should means sync_with_stdio(false). Then if I keep sync_with_stdio(true), does this mean that the system will not output interleaved characters with cout? Thanks!

Comment: "Concurrent access" is defined in **[intro.races]** It does not have anything to do with `sync_with_stdio`.

Comment: No, it does not mean that.   The first para says that concurrent access will not create a data race, so there is no incidental chance of data corruption (e.g. of stream buffers) due to being used from multiple threads.   The note reflects the fact that the stream can't control how it is used by code outside itself - so if two threads perform unsynchronised operations on the same stream, the order of those operations is unspecified - one possible outcome of that is interleaved characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note 1 means that if I concurrent access to a synchronized standard `iostream` object there will be no interleaved character

No, the note states that, while there is no race, interleaved characters may occur - so, quite the opposite of your conclusion. `sync_with_stdio(true)` does not mean "thread synchronized" as in "one line at a time no matter how many threads that uses it". It's about the synchronization between `cout`/`cin` and the underlying C streams. When `true`, the output to `cout` is immediately applied to the `stdout` C stream for example.

> How the C++ avoid interleaved characters for `cout`?

I assume you wonder how you can assure that there are no interleaved characters when using `cout` from multiple threads. If so, synchronize the use of `cout`. In C++20 and later, you can use a [`std::osyncstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream)and prior to that you can use a `std::mutex` for that.

Answer (score 1):

The first paragraph means that the streams must handle concurrent access (aka, they must never crash), and that all of the bytes will be written in an unspecified order.

The second paragraph clarifies that they *can and often do* interleave characters.